# How to optimize a code to function and call it through button C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, optimization, unity-game-engine

While doing combo box using buttons I just caught myself on idea, is it possible to make something like: "wanna more? ok. press and get it :)" for instance I have combo boxes with a fruits, vegetables, berries. So, I selected fruit, vegetable, berry and I want to repeat the same combo boxes with a list of fruits, vegetables, berries. Probably I may need something like "Add new fruit, vegetable, berry". So my question is: Is it possible to do "Add new fruit, vegetable, berry", if so please give some feedback :D Regards, Tim

Here is a code an example code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class hibye: MonoBehaviour 
{

    public string slectedItem = "None";
    private bool editing = false;

     public string slectedItem2 = "None";
    private bool editing2 = false;

    public string slectedItem3 = "None";
    private bool editing3 = false;

    private void OnGUI()
    {   
        if ( GUILayout.Button(slectedItem))
        {
            editing = true;
        }

        if (editing)
        {
         string[] sig = {"Banana","Apple","Orange"};

            for (int x = 0; x < sig.Length ; x++)
            {
                if (GUILayout.Button(sig[x]))
                {
                    slectedItem = sig[x];
                    editing = false;

                }
            }
        }
          if ( GUILayout.Button(slectedItem2))
        {
            editing2 = true;
        }

        if (editing2)
        {
         string[] sig = {"Cabbage","Potato","Paprika"};

            for (int x = 0; x < sig.Length ; x++)
            {
                if (GUILayout.Button(sig[x]))
                {
                    slectedItem2 = sig[x];
                    editing2 = false;

                }
            }
        }
          if ( GUILayout.Button(slectedItem3))
        {
            editing3 = true;
        }

        if (editing3)
        {
         string[] sig = {"Baneberry","Blackberry","Grape"};

            for (int x = 0; x < sig.Length ; x++)
            {
                if (GUILayout.Button(sig[x]))
                {
                    slectedItem3 = sig[x];
                    editing3 = false;

                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I want to make the code shortest and add another GUILayout.Button which allows me to make choice of existing items one more time without changing existing chosen items.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry. "The botanical definition of a berry is a fleshy fruit produced from a single ovary"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to meet the scope requirements that you have clearly laid out.  I wish you luck in your excursion.